# Determining the type of conic from the parameterization $(t^2+t+1,t^2-t+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

In the question the parametric coordinate of a conic is given by $(t^2+t+1,t^2-t+1)$

In questions which are similar to this I would just go on by writing "X=x coordinate expression" and similarly "Y = y coordinate expression" and then get value of "t" in terms of x and y after which i would equate both the values of "t" to get the locus expression from where determining conic type is easy.

But in this expression the parametric is in quadratic i am unable to figure out how to proceed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [@A.Goodier's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4686753/409) shows the clever approach, but it's worth noting that you *could* power through using the strategy you outlined. Solving quadratics $t^2+t+1=x$ and $t^2-t+1=y$ gives
$$t = \frac12\left(-1+p\sqrt{4x-3}\right) \qquad t = \frac12\left(1+q\sqrt{4y-3}\right)$$ where $p$ and $q$ are each $\pm1$ (though they may not match) so that $p^2=q^2=1$. Setting the values of $t$ equal gives $$p\sqrt{4x-3}=2+q\sqrt{4y-3}$$ A couple of rounds of squaring will eliminate the roots (and nullify the ambiguity in $p$ and $q$). Tedious, but doable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtracting, we have $x-y=2t$, so $t=\dfrac{x-y}{2}$ .

Hence
$$\begin{aligned}x=\frac{(x-y)^2}{4}+\frac{x-y}{2}+1
&\iff (x-y)^2+2(x-y)-4x+4=0 \\
&\iff (x-y+1)^2-4x+3=0\\
\end{aligned}$$

Now make a change of variables $Y:=x-y+1, X:=x-\frac34$ . Then $Y^2=4X$, which is a parabola.

Comment: One can also put the equation of the parabola in axis/vertex tangent form: $$(-2\sqrt2)(\frac{(x-1)+(y-1)}{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt2}(\frac{(x-1)-(y-1)}{\sqrt2})^2)=0.$$

Using this $y'=\frac1{4f} x'^2$ for $f=\frac1{2\sqrt2}.$ That is $(2f s,f s^2)$ with rotation $\frac{\pi}4.$ The standard parametrization therefore is $(x,y)=(1,1)+(\frac{\frac{s}{\sqrt2}+\frac{s^2}{2\sqrt2}}{\sqrt2},\frac{\frac{s}{\sqrt2}-\frac{s^2}{2\sqrt2}}{\sqrt2})=(1+\frac{s}2+\frac{s^2}4,1-\frac{s}2+\frac{s^2}4)$ which is OP's for $t=\frac{s}2.$

Comment: One can also put the equation of the parabola in focus/directrix form: $$2((x-\frac54)^2+(y-\frac54)^2-(x+y-\frac32)^2/2)=0.$$

Answer (score -1):

$$x=\left(t+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34;\qquad y=\left(t-\frac12\right)^2+\frac34$$
Thus we have $t=\sqrt{x-\dfrac34}-\dfrac12$ so that

$$\left(t-\dfrac12\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{x-\dfrac34}-1\right)^2=x-\dfrac34+1-2\sqrt{x-\dfrac34}
=x+\frac14-2\bigg(t+\frac12\bigg)=x-2t-\frac34$$

This gives $$y=x-2t$$ so that $(y-x)^2=4\left(x-\frac34\right)=4x-3$, or $$y^2+x^2-2xy-4x+3=0.$$
Following https://brilliant.org/wiki/conics-discriminant, we check the discriminant $$\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}1 &&-1&&-2\\-1&&1&&0\\-2 && 0&&3\end{vmatrix}=3+1(-3)-2(2)=3-3-4=-4.$$ Since $\Delta\neq0$, we check $B^2-4AC=h^2-ab=0$, which gives a parabola.